# 'Cold' tab to show questions with low views?

Tags: feature-request

Opposite to the 'Hot' tab, the 'Cold' tab would show questions with the least views, answers and votes for the past week, allowing them to get a little attention.

Whether that attention be answers, general cleanup/editing or even the unfortunate close vote for a few unsalvagable questions, better for them to be noticed then dissappearing into the void of untouched questions to be eventually purged from the system.

Thoughts?

Comment: To some extent, the [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/) link already provides some of this functionality.

Comment: Kind of. The review tab is more for showing questions and answers from new users and questions flagged as low quality. What i'm suggesting is more along the lines of the 'Tumbleweed' badge- questions which have received little to no attention- irrespective of join date or rep count

Comment: How about an "un-loved" tab for low favorites?