# Ways to spur more views for low view questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions

Would there be any logical way to provide a "suggested questions" list/queue of low view/response questions to users somewhere based on the tags they've been active in?

I tend to run across some good(yes I realize that's subjective) questions with very low views that are apparently asked at odd times or just somehow slip through the cracks. Sometimes they are especially difficult and people looking for easy answers just move on. Right now the major mechanism to promote more exposure to a question is the bounty system.

Are there other mechanisms in place I'm missing here?

This question is in a similar vein to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135748/cold-tab-to-show-questions-with-low-views).

Comment: People active in tags and interested in them *already* follow such tags. Through RSS for example. I do, for several low-traffic tags.

Comment: The [Community process](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) randomly bumps old, unanswered questions to give them more attention.

Comment: @RobertHarvey When you say unanswered, does that mean ones without accepted answers or ones with 0 answers?

Comment: @MagicMan: [from Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/220428): _Note that the posts eligible for bumping have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed)._

Comment: Thanks @Qantas94Heavy I'm guessing this topic is a little tired over here? Many of the questions I'm referring to are fairly low rep users questions so usually the bounty is unlikely(unless another user does it for them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounty system seems like it is working out fine. After all, there is a reason that questions have a low number of views, and that is because people are uninterested in them. By incentivizing boring, neglected, or difficult questions, there will be answers for them.

Any way of spurring more views (besides forcefully redirecting users to the question) seems like it won't really fix the problem. If there a good reason for users not to answer, then I don't know why they would click on the question in the "suggested" list.

And it also seems like you are one of many people who find the "good" neglected questions that you mentioned. It seems like others do the same thing that you do, so I don't think that there is a big issue with the current system.

Comment: Part of what I'm getting at is a visibility & sustainability issue, I have to go actively looking for things that interest me. It would be nice if there was some queue/list of things that might interest me. It is tough to consistently search out things. A feature like I'm suggesting wouldn't completely solve the problem by any means; it might be a feature only a small percentage of users would use but I think it would contribute to overall knowledge base building.